# form submit is not working when i click button

Tags: php

Why isn't my form working and why are there no errors showing? When I click the submit button nothing happens, here is my code:

```
<?php
$list_of_product=$p->loadSearchProduct($searchkey);

foreach ($list_of_product as $product) {
   echo "<tr>"
   .'<form id ="myForm" action = "InsertOrders.php" method = "POST">'
   ."<td>".$product->prodname."</td>"
   ."<td>".$product->price."</td>"
   ."<td>".$product->total." "."Piece(s)"."</td>"
   ."<td>".$product->remaining_stock." "."Piece(s)"."</td>"
   ."<td>".$product->sold_stock."</td>"
   ."<td>"."<input class='form-control' name='qty' type='text' required/>"."</td>"   
   ."<td>"."<button type='submit' id='sub' class='btn btn-primary'>"."<b>Add to List</b>"."</button>"."</td>"
   ."</form>"
   ."</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried this exact code with several forms, and all of the submit their own form (using a custom class to represent the products)

Comment: Adding a unique name for each submit button could help the backend distinguish which form is being submitted, i.e. `<button type="submit" name=prodname ...></button>` and in the backend `isset($_POST['prodname'])`

Comment: i will not get a value from a button...

Comment: and i've tried naming it by the product id which is unique and it still doesn't work

Comment: In the file that it POSTs to (InsertOrders.php), have you tried to `var_dump($_POST)` , if the post goes through to the file `$_POST['qty]` should be set

Comment: it doesn't redirect to the action page... and it doesn't show errors when i click the add to list button nothing happens.

Comment: Make sure you fill something in in the input field, otherwise the browser prevents the submit since the input field is marked as `required`

Comment: yea bro i did it and besides.. i'm using bootstrap so if i leave it blank there should be a validation..

Comment: which browsers have you tried using? are you using any javascript for prevention?

Comment: @jasonA is a new user. Questions like this are normal. But people downvoted it.

Comment: can we see InsertOrders.php?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have several forms with the same id.

When you click submit, it es not specific witch one is clicked.

**EDIT**

```
        $count = 0;
foreach ($list_of_product as $product) {
       echo "<tr>"
       .'<form id ="myForm" action = "InsertOrders.php" method = "POST">'
       ."<td>".$product->prodname."</td>"
       ."<td>".$product->price."</td>"
       ."<td>".$product->total." "."Piece(s)"."</td>"
       ."<td>".$product->remaining_stock." "."Piece(s)"."</td>"
       ."<td>".$product->sold_stock."</td>"
       ."<td>"."<input class='form-control' name='qty' type='text' required/>"."</td>"   
       ."<td>"."<button type='submit' id='sub".$count."' class='btn btn-primary'>"."<b>Add to List</b>"."</button>"."</td>"
       ."</form>"
       ."</tr>";
       $count++;
    }
```

When you use an counter, you can check in you InsertOrders.php which one is clicked. Its not the best way, but it will be work.

Comment: but i will only get value in a form which i clicked.. what should i do..

Comment: i've already tried assigning the id with unique but it still doesn't work

Comment: @jasonA So what you are saying is that you want to submit all the add values with one single button?

Comment: nah.. i want only the value from a form which i clicked

Answer (score 0):

i think if you can use form tags outside of the `foreach`, it will submit. Or else try remove 'id' attribute in your code.